# Good books about elliptic integralsa, hypergeometric and special functions

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, elliptic-integrals

Can you please tell me some good books from where I can learn elliptic integrals and special functions like hypergeometric functions?

Answer (score 3):

Whittaker and Watson, *Modern Analysis*, is the obvious first choice.

For just identities, there's the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov).

Comment: Is it the book where they say "shew" instead of "show" ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM That's entirely standard in English (or at least Cambridge) books of that period. G.H. Hardy's *A Course in Pure Mathematics* does the same (see p. 28 of https://archive.org/details/coursepuremath00hardrich, for example), and it's all over the Tripos papers of that period, and reviews in the mathematical journals.